# What is "content loaded as chrome?"

Tags: firefox, css, mozilla

> **-moz-user-select**
>
> Controls the appearance (only) of
>   selection.  This does not have any
>   affect on actual selection operation. 
>   **This doesn't have any effect on content loaded as chrome**, except in
>   textboxes.

Source: [link text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select)

I know what `-moz-user-select` does, but what is "content loaded as chrome?"

Thanks

Comment: Chrome here refers to the Firefox user interface - the awesome bar, the back buttons, the menus, back buttons, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome) in mozilla refers to several things, but the underlying idea is that it's anything that's presented as the web browser's own user interface, as opposed to the contents of a web page. Chrome can contain text that is styled using CSS; but because of possible security issues, you can't change certain aspects of it's appearance using the page's CSS.